# android detect device width

Tags: android, layout, adaptive-ui

is there a way to detect device width so that we can add views programmatically based on device screen width. For example, single or dual pane.

Right now, the way for adpative UI is using layout XML for different device size. This is not flexible enough in our case.

```
layout-small/
layout-large/
layout-sw600dp/
```

The preferred way for us is: layout.xml defines the root empty container only, and add views programmatically based on device size that is detected at runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to set yourself up for a world of pain that way.  Odds are your "not flexible enough" is really you doing something wrong.  There's a reason why that approach is avoided at almost all costs on Android.  Your example there is a classic example of something Android is actually really good at.

Answer (score 2):

U can use this code to get runtime Device's display Width & Height

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

U can set like

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: U can set width using that parameter

Answer (score 1):

This code will support all version of android device Resolution(Width, Height) accurately at runtime

```
private void calculateDeviceResolution(Activity context) {
        Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            //new pleasant way to get real metrics
            DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics);
            realWidth = realMetrics.widthPixels;
            realHeight = realMetrics.heightPixels;

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            //reflection for this weird in-between time
            try {
                Method mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
                Method mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
                realWidth = (Integer) mGetRawW.invoke(display);
                realHeight = (Integer) mGetRawH.invoke(display);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //this may not be 100% accurate, but it's all we've got
                realWidth = display.getWidth();
                realHeight = display.getHeight();
                Constants.errorLog("Display Info", "Couldn't use reflection to get the real display metrics.");
            }

        } else {
            //This should be close, as lower API devices should not have window navigation bars
            realWidth = display.getWidth();
            realHeight = display.getHeight();
        }
    }
```

after getting the width or height you can set like this

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(realWidth , realHeight ));
```

Answer (score 1):

In an activity,

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int height = dm.heightPixels;
int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

In a fragment,

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int height = dm.heightPixels;
int width = dm.widthPixels;
```